# Remove leading 0 in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to create a big table without leading zeros using siunitx `\num{}`. Namely, I have a bunch of number formated like this:

```
0.001
0.1
1.000
```

and I want to remove the 0. part. So the output would be:

```
.001
.1
1.000
```

It should be the opposite of add-integer-zero option (something like remove-integer-zero). I have triyed lots of `\sisetup` configuration without luck. All question in tex exchange seems to be the opposite to what I want. Any idea of it is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us an MWE showing your table. Do you need any other `siunitx` actions like aligning?

Comment: Removing the leading zero is not recommended.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: `\sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}` is the way to remove the leading zero, but don't do it.

Comment: @egreg: `add-integer-zero=false` will not *add* an integer zero, `.001` would be kept, but the option does not *remove* a zero from the input. AFAIK the requested feature is not supported by `siunitx`.

Comment: `.000` would look quite funny, if the most "significant" zero is suppressed and the other zeroes are kept.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, it will not remove the digit if already in the input. But if it's not wanted, it shouldn't be there to begin with. However, BIPM's recommendations are to *always* have the integer part, even if it's zero, see http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter5/5-3-2.html#5-3-4

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answares. I know it is a bad practice but I am only following orders (seems that this is common practice in some social sciences fields).

Comment: It is in common use when discussing probabilities, for instance, where the number _cannot_ be above 1.

Comment: @egreg link seems broken

Comment: @Ludwik I get “the BIPM site is being updated”. I see the brochure at https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf

Comment: @egreg yeah I saw the same (but title is a 404). So the link you gave now is useful, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments about this not being a good idea.  But having said that, here's an approach, using the `expl3` syntax that `siunitx` is built upon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\trimleadingzero{m}{%%
  \fp_compare:nTF { 0 < \fp_abs:n { #1 } < 1 }
    { 
      \__trimleadingzero:n {#1}
    }
    { #1 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__trimleadingzero:n #1 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ae_integer_decimal_parts_seq {.} {#1}
  \fp_compare:nF {#1>0}
    { - }
  .\seq_item:Nn \l_ae_integer_decimal_parts_seq {2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\SI[add-integer-zero=false,parse-numbers=false]{\trimleadingzero{0.03}}{}

\SI[add-integer-zero=false,parse-numbers=false]{\trimleadingzero{-0.03}}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code but I am afraid that does not work in my setup. Will I need a special version of expl3?

Comment: @cruzki The above code should work with the most recent version of LaTeX.  You might want to update your system.

Comment: I have test both in Texlive 2013 (up to date gentoo linux unstable) and MikTex 2.9 (windows 7). I have tested both pdflatex and lualatex without luck (the leading 0 is still presented).

Comment: @cruzki If everything is up-to-date, then I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.  Perhaps you should post a new question showing what you've tried so we can try to figure out why it's not working for you.  I know that's a bit of a lame response, but without knowing more about what you're doing, it's hard to say.  One thing you could try is add `\listfiles` in your preamble.  That will inform you about versions of packages.  When I do that it tells me that  my version of `expl3` is `expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper`

Comment: The problem is that the example you have provide is not working (and I do not have any experience with expl3 to debug the problem). It seems that my expl3 is almost a yera old compared with yours. I will try to update it.     \listfiles   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

Comment: @cruzki Today is a very busy day, but I might have time this evening (I'm in California) to work on an approach that doesn't rely on `expl3`.  But it will probably be a bit more convoluted.

Comment: Ok, ussing your version of expl3 the example provided works. Now I have to make some changes in my code. Thanks a lot  A.Ellett :)